# Blazor: Update using InvokeAsync causes memory leak

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor app with a list that I want to update automatically using a Timer every X seconds. When I run the app using the following code, the list is refreshed every 10 seconds, but the memory usage rises on every refresh. The memory usage of the app starts at 2-300 MB and rises past 1 GB within 10 refreshes.

I was hoping that my code would overwrite the existing list on every refresh, thus not using more and more memory. What am I missing? Could it be because the refreshing is done in multiple threads?

```cs
public partial class MyBlazorComponent
{
    private Dictionary<Guid, IList<MyModel>> MyList { get; set; }
    private Timer Timer { get; set; }
    
    // A simple lock to make sure that multiple refreshes don't overlap
    private bool _isRefreshing;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await UpdateMyList(); // the initial loading of the list
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        Timer = new Timer(async _ =>
        {
            await RefreshList();
        }, null, 0, 10000);
    }

    private async Task UpdateMyList()
    {
        _isRefreshing = true;
        MyList = null;
        MyList = await _myService.GetList(); // external service to get list contents
        _isRefreshing = false;
    }
    
    private async Task RefreshList()
    {
        if (!_isRefreshing)
        {
            // Without these two lines, the list won't update
            MyList = null; 
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            
            // Update the list
            await UpdateMyList();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a small version of the code you shared (https://blazorfiddle.com/s/sr0spgs8), but I'm not running into the issues you're describing. When I run it locally I also don't notice a memory leak. Something special to notice as well is that I don't need to invoke StateHasChanged twice for the list to change. Could you share some of the razor code and perhaps also more details about the Service? To me it doesn't seem like the issue is in the code you provided.

Comment: Why are you using `StateHasChanged`, much less `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` ? Replacing the list will cause a redraw of only the affected elements. `StateHasChanged` will trigger an update of the entire page. `InvokeAsync` .... what's the point of that? Have you tried simply calling `UpdateMyList` in the timer?

Comment: BTW which Blazor version are you using? Server-side or web assembly? *Old* Blazor versions needed `StateHasChanged`, .NET 5 doesn't

Comment: @Nijenhof I think you are on to something.. I did some debugging and it seems that the memory use increase when the service is invoked, not when the list is rendered in the Blazor component. I will investigate some more, but it looks like this has nothing do with Blazor

Comment: Side note, you _are_ leaking the Timer but that won't cause the memory use you are seeing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - you are now spreading misinformation. The timer fires a non-Blazor event and you do need StateHasChanged to see its effects. And InvokeAsync is required on the server, advisable for WebAssembly.

Comment: And of course @Nijenhof is right, the problem is _myService.GetList().

Comment: Completely overlooked that one @HenkHolterman. This should indeed implement IDispose to get rid of the timer once it's no longer in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue here is not in the code provided, but the statement _myService.GetList(). As @HenkHolterman has keenly observed, the only memory-leak in this code is that the timer is not disposed of when the component is no longer in use. This can be done like:

```
public partial class MyBlazorComponent : IDisposable
{
    private Timer Timer { get; set; }

    //other code.....

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```